# Custom jQuery Plugin with JSONP callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a custom jQuery plugin which loads data from flickr.

Therefore I'm using [starter from pixelgraphics](http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/).

How can I define a callback function which lies within my scope?

I tried the following, but all functions are undefined:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
        method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
        api_key: base.apiKey,
        photoset_id: base.setID,
        format: 'json',
        jsoncallback: base.processData
        //jsoncallback: 'base.processData'
        //jsoncallback: processData
        //jsoncallback: this.processData
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
});
base.processData = function(data) {
     console.log(data);
};
```

**Edit:**

Unfortunately pszaba's solution doesn't work. A working solution is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&format=json&api_key=" + base.apiKey + "&photoset_id=" + base.setID + "&jsoncallback=?",
    type: "GET",
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        base.processData(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
jsonpCallback: "processData"
```

and don't forget define the function

```
function processData(json) {}
```

**EDIT**

You can also use the 'context'

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    context: base,
    ...
```

and later you can call like:

```
jsoncallback: this.processData
```

Comment: please read the question. base is my scope and I want to call the function base.processData()